# Pycharm: ImportError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm developping a chat app using Pycharm IDE. I have multiple directories in my project folder, and I want to perform import from some of dirs but I can't, I got this error
. Note that I could do the import before, but now I can't. I don't know what happen.
`ImportError: No module named 'src'`

This is a picture of the error and the hierarchy of files.

[image]

Comment: Never post images of code on SO. Not only is copy-pasting easier, it's more legible. Post the relevant code and error messages in an understandable format (ctrl-k may help).

Comment: @JemiSalo I posted the image to show the files hierarchy and the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a module named src in the directory.

This error basically means that the module is not present.

Rebuild the project and it should solve your problem.

Comment: You can see the src directory in the image, I underlined it with red color

Comment: Yesy I can see that. But this error occurs due to the compiler not able to recognize utility package in your project. Import the project once again and see if it resolves the issue